# Can't use comma inside backtick column name for data.table setkey?

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, reshape2

If I have a column name that needs backticks because it contains a comma, `setkey` throws an error saying don't use a comma.  The error directs me towards `?setkey` but I don't see anything in the examples there that mentions this.  Only work around I can find is to rename the column, `setkey` and then rename back.

Example code:

```
library(data.table)
> DT = data.table(`X, in $` = rnorm(10))
> DT
        X, in $
 1: -1.28475886
 2:  0.97789059
 3: -0.05023914
 4: -0.38133978
 5: -0.24949607
 6:  0.99213156
 7: -0.29310512
 8:  0.02840372
 9:  0.25294231
10: -0.88955013
> setkey(DT, `X, in $`)
Error in setkeyv(x, cols, verbose = verbose) : 
  Don't use comma inside quotes. Please see the examples in help('setkey')
```

**Edit: showing a more likely example**

For me the main reason you would come across this is after using `reshape2` `dcast` to take character column values (which will be from an external source, e.g. database) and make them column names.

So long as you don't need the "join" behaviour of the key, and just wanted to sort, then you can work around this by copying the table, or by using `data.frame` instead.  For example:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

DT = data.table(Office = rep(c("Cambridge, UK", "Cambridge, US", "London", "New York"), each = 12), Product = rep(1:12,4), Sales = rnorm(48)^2)
DF = dcast(DT, Product~Office)
DT = data.table(DF)
setkey(DT, 'Cambridge, UK')
DT = DT[order(DF$`Cambridge, UK`),]
DT
```

produces:

```
> library(ggplot2)
> library(reshape2)
> 
> DT = data.table(Office = rep(c("Cambridge, UK", "Cambridge, US", "London", "New York"), each = 12), Product = rep(1:12,4), Sales = rnorm(48)^2)
> DF = dcast(DT, Product~Office)
Using Sales as value column: use value.var to override.
> DT = data.table(DF)
> setkey(DT, 'Cambridge, UK')
Error in setkeyv(x, cols, verbose = verbose) : 
  Don't use comma inside quotes. Please see the examples in help('setkey')
> DT = DT[order(DF$`Cambridge, UK`),]
> DT
    Product Cambridge, UK Cambridge, US      London    New York
 1:      12  0.0009257347  1.7183751269 0.818101229 0.002499808
 2:       1  0.0010855828  0.0889560105 0.083778108 1.451149328
 3:       2  0.0139649148  0.7385617360 0.221688602 4.771307440
 4:       5  0.0520875574  0.3389613574 0.934932759 0.127634044
 5:      10  0.0837778446  0.0598955035 0.015930174 0.715849795
 6:       9  0.0856246191  1.1303900183 1.555058058 0.367063297
 7:       6  0.1608235273  0.7147643550 0.004588596 2.995598768
 8:       8  0.4797866129  0.1783997616 0.016459971 0.497328990
 9:       4  0.5282546636  1.7011670679 0.016126768 0.024388172
10:       7  0.5655147714  0.1106522938 0.045130643 0.442473457
11:       3  0.8315246051  0.1399159784 5.792956446 1.632060601
12:      11  3.9958208033  0.0005297928 0.003282897 1.635506818
```

Comment: Why can't you simply use valid names?

Comment: @Roland The column names will automatically be used for the label and legends etc in generated plots and reports. One solution is simply to avoid it and manually set the output string, like one would in python or languages that don't support escaped variable names, but it would be nice not to have to. My understanding was that one was encouraged to use the display name in your data structures, hence the backtick mechanism.

Comment: No, that's not encouraged. Save the output for printing in a separate character vector.

Comment: @Roland So what *is* the point of backticks then?  Why does R allow arbitrary object names?

Comment: Sometimes they're required when coercing between places where otherwise illegal names are allowed and where they're not allowed. Imagine a situation like: `x <- c(1,2,3); names(x) <- c('a','b',3); names(x); as.list(x)`.

Comment: If it turns out the answer is simply, "rename the columns before you start" or use `order` then that is fine.  I'm happy to close the question.  I just thought it was odd as it was the only place I've had this problem.

Comment: All philosophical differences aside on whether this naming scheme is a good idea, I think this is a bug and you should file a bug report.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE (eddi):** As of [version 1.8.11](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/NEWS?view=markup&root=datatable&pathrev=994) this bug has been fixed and arbitrary column names will work with `setkey`.

---

I found a hack: (1) sort and (2) `settattr`.

**Example:**

```
mydt <- data.table(`b,ah`=c(2L,3:1),var=letters[1:4])

mydt <- mydt[order(`b,ah`)]
setattr(mydt,'sorted','b,ah')
```

Now, to verify that it behaves well...

```
key(mydt)
# [1] "b,ah"
mydt[.(2)]
#    b,ah var
# 1:    2   a
# 2:    2   c
mydt[,.N,by=`b,ah`]
#    b,ah N
# 1:    1 1
# 2:    2 2
# 3:    3 1
```

**Comments.** I didn't use the OP's example because setting <s>numeric</s> big floating-point columns as keys is weird (to me).

Who knows what negative side effects this could have? Anyway, I wouldn't use it, and agree it would be nice to have commas supported. Maybe there could be a `setkeyn` for setting by column number if it makes too much of a mess in `setkey`/`setkeyv`?

Comment: Frank, you are right. I've been a sloppy reader all day, I had read that and was thinking numbers. my bad.

Comment: Great answer - this was the sort of thing I was looking for.  Yes my example was silly in that sense - but you can use float-point columns for rolling joins.

Comment: @eddi: Nice; that was fast! Maybe you meant to edit the question instead of the answer...? Either way, it might make sense to put the update at the top of the question (to save people from taking the time to understand a historical/now-irrelevant bug).